# Why is the console throwing " Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I've declared all the variables and then stored all the elements accordingly.

Then I've declared two functions.

Finally I've created two event listeners, where the two functions I created have been passed as call back.

Although I seem to have followed all the proper steps I can't identify why the console is throwing : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at index.js:32".

If you could point out where I've made a mistake that would be great.

```js
var elForm, elSelectPackage, elPackageHint, elTerms, elTermsHint;

elForm = document.getElementById("formSignUp");
elSelectPackage = document.getElementById("package");
elPackageHint = document.getElementById("packageHint");
elTerms = document.getElementById("terms");
elTermsHint = document.getElementById("termsHint");

function packageHint(){
  var package = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  if(package === "Monday") {
    elPackageHint.innerHTML = "You get 10% off";
  } else {
    elPackageHint.innerHTML = "Wise choice"
  }
}

function checkTerms(event) {
  if (!elTerms.checked) {
    elTermsHint.innerHTML = "you must agree to term & conditions"
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

elForm.addEventListener('submit', checkTerms, false);
elSelectPackage.addEventListener("change", packageHint, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Practise App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>


  <body>
    <h1 id="packageHint"></h1>
    <form method="post" id="formSignUp" action="http://www.example.org/register">
      <select class="package" name="">
        <option value="">Monday</option>
        <option value="">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="">Wednesday</option>
      </select><br>
    </form>
    <input id="terms" type="checkbox" name="" value="">
    <div>check to agree terms and conditions</div>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you do :
`elSelectPackage = document.getElementById("package");`
But `package` is a class, not an ID